# angularjs custom button directive submit different forms

Tags: angularjs, directive

I created a styled button directive. I just wanted that button submit form which is included inside.

```
angular.module('app')
.directive('gpButton', function () {
    return {
        templateUrl: "views/directives/components/button.html",
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            type: '@',
            background: '@'
        },
        transclude: true,
        controllerAs: "vm",
        bindToController: true,
        controller: [function() {
            var vm = this;
        }]
    };
});
```

And here is my button.html file;

```
<button class="button"
    type="{{vm.type === 'submit' ? 'submit' : 'button'}}"
    ng-disabled="{{vm.disabled ? true : false}}"
    ng-style="{'background': vm.background}">
<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
</button>
```

And my one the form is going to be like,

```
     <form name="individualLoginForm" ng-submit="vm.submitIndLogin()">
       <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 100px;">
           <gp-input type="tel"
                     autofocus="true"
                     autocomplete="off"
                     phone-input="true"
                     ng-model="vm.loginPhoneNumber"
                     label="{{'GSM_NUMBER' | translate}}"
                     icon-class="gp-icon icon-phone"
                     disabled="vm.firstFormSubmitted"
                     required="true">
           </gp-input>
        </div>
        <gp-button type="submit" ---> here is my custom submit button
                   background="#E57373">
         Login
        </gp-button>
    </form>
```

But it's only submitting when the refreshing the page, if I go to the other route and come back it's not submitting the form. What should I do for submit which included into any `<form></form>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the interpolation `{{ }}` from the `ng-disabled` directive:

```
<button class="button"
    type="{{vm.type === 'submit' ? 'submit' : 'button'}}"
    ̶n̶g̶-̶d̶i̶s̶a̶b̶l̶e̶d̶=̶"̶{̶{̶v̶m̶.̶d̶i̶s̶a̶b̶l̶e̶d̶ ̶?̶ ̶t̶r̶u̶e̶ ̶:̶ ̶f̶a̶l̶s̶e̶}̶}̶"̶
    ng-disabled="vm.disabled ? true : false"
    ng-style="{'background': vm.background}">
  <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
</button>
```

From the Docs:

> ## ng-disabled
>
> A special directive is necessary because we cannot use interpolation inside the `disabled` attribute. See the [interpolation guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation) for more info.
>
> [— AngularJS `ng-disabled` Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled)

Comment: I'll try it asap

Comment: It worked. Thanks, I'm missed that cause of other property types.